# Selecting event within date span in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to work out how to write my query statement in Django to select all Events that occur within a date range. An Event has a `ManyToMany` field `schedules` that points to one or more Schedule objects. Basically it looks like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  schedules = models.ManyToManyField(Schedule)

class Schedule(models.Model):
    from_date = models.DateTimeField(default="1970-01-01", blank=True)
    to_date = models.DateTimeField(default="1970-01-01", blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('from_date', 'to_date',)
```

So an event can have many scheduled occasions like this:

```
Event   |  from_date  | to_date
----------------------------------
event1  | 2013-01-01  | 2013-01-02 (1)
        | 2013-01-04  | 2013-01-07 (2)
        | 2013-01-01  | 2013-04-30 (3)

event2  | 2013-01-01  | 2013-01-03 (4)
        | 2013-01-02  | 2013-01-10 (5)
        | 2013-02-10  | 2013-04-15 (6)
...
```

If I have an event like `event1` with a schedule like `schedule (3)`, I would like that event to be returned using the February-filter. In this case, `event2` should also be returned since it has `schedule (6)`.

This is how I try to select these events:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(
            Q(schedules__from_date__gte=from_date) & 
            Q(schedules__to_date__lte=to_date))
events = events.distinct()
```

This does not give me correct results when I try to filter out all events that occur in February with a date range like this: `(2013-02-01,2013-02-28)`.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(
         Q(schedules__from_date__gte=from_date) | Q(schedules__to_date__gte=from_date), 
         Q(schedules__to_date__lte=to_date) | Q(schedules__from_date__lte=to_date))
events = events.distinct()
```

Hope it helps!
For a full explanation on the Q class you can see the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

As for the logic, what we are doing is getting the events whose schedules START or FINISH after our "from date". If it started after, we need the START or FINISH date to be lower than our "to date". If it started before, we need it to finish in the interval, so it will satisfy the condition too.

It is kinda complicated to explain, I will elaborate better later!

Comment: Oh the awesomeness. If you have time to provide an explanation on why/how this works I'd love to hear it :)

Comment: Thanks for explanation, no need to elaborate further. It's obvious now!